# Merging multiple rows with same value

Tags: ms-access

I need to transform the table on the left into into the format of the table on the right. The original table is in MS Access and I am struggling with this problem.

I found many examples where this was done with min/max aggregated function, but since there are multiple rows for each value, this does not work.

[image: img]

Comment: You say "the original table is in Access".  Is the other one not in Access?

Comment: There is only the original table (left one). I want to produce a table like the right one with query.

Comment: answer is below

Answer (score 1):

Your tables don't appear to be consistent -

For example, the six original values associated with Type `A` (highlighted in yellow in the left-hand table below), become six different values (as highlighted in yellow in the right-hand table):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To transform (or "pivot") an Access table, you need a ***Crosstab Query***.

The easiest way to create a Crosstab Query is with the **Crosstab Query Wizard**.

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**Create a crosstab query by using the Crosstab Query Wizard**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8#crosstab_wizard)
- YouTube : [**Create a Crosstab Query**](https://youtu.be/RVFgjMDeGaw)
- Paragon : [**What is a CrossTab Query?**](http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=25)

Comment: I was able to produce a table like this (link below) with the crosstab query, since the original table contains multiple rows for each ID, the examples in those videos dont apply to this situation IMO.

https://puu.sh/A0l1v/293923ff0b.png